# Use iterated object in class attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this code:

```
@foreach (var know in Model.Items)
{

    <span class="cloud@know.Value"></span>
}
```

What I want to do is add a different (css-)class on the span, depending on the value of the Know object, so the classes i have are `cloud1`, `cloud2`, `cloud3` etc.

But in my code, literally the text `cloud@know.Value` is parsed; the `know.value` is not replaced.

It does work when I type this `cloud_@know.Value`.

Is there a way to do this without adding the underscore to the classnames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap `know.Value` in parentheses:

```
@foreach (var know in Model.Items)
{
    <span class="cloud@(know.Value)"></span>
}
```

Comment: whoot! that works. I tried a lot of things, but not parentheses like this.